# How many distinct ways can the number be written as product of $3$ factors?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many distinct ways can the number $126$ be written as a product of $3$ positive integer  factors?
I found that the prime factors are $126=2\times3\times3\times7$. But how to get number of different ways out of this?

Comment: Is the expression $2\times 63\times 1$ to be considered different from $1\times 2\times 63$?

Comment: @André Nicolas: No

Answer (score 4):

We're trying to count factorizations $126=abc$ with $a\le b\le c$.  Note that, except for $1\cdot1\cdot126$ and $3\cdot3\cdot14$, the rest have $a\lt b\lt c$, since $3$ is the only repeated prime factor of $126$.  Let $m$ denote the number with $a\lt b\lt c$, so the number we want to find is $m+2$.

If we remove the condition $a\le b\le c$, the number of factorizations $126=abc$ is $6m+3\cdot2=6m+6$.  But it's also $3\cdot6\cdot3=54$, since the $2$ and $7$ can be assigned to any of the three factors and the pair of $3$'s can be assigned in $6$ different ways.  Setting $6m+6=54$, we find $m=8$, so the answer we're after is $8+2=10$.

Comment: You meant $6m + \color{red}{6} = 54$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, yes, thanks.  Fixed now.

Comment: Where does 6m come from?

Comment: @ReeSSult, when $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all different, there are $6$ ways to permute them, hence the $6m$.

Answer (score 1):

(I made a mistake in the first version of this answer, it should be fixed now)

(As pointed out by @DougM there was also a mistake in the second version, that is also fixed now)

$126$ is so small that it's probably faster to just list the ways, but here's a very detailed argument.

Any factor is a product of some of the prime factors, so as you have those, it's just a question of combining those into 3 factors, and combining them into two factors (and taking $1$ as the third factor). For combining them into two factors, you also have to remember that both factors can be a product of two, or one can be one of the prime factors and the other a product of the remaining three. There is also the trivial way of having two factors of $1$.

Pairing them uo two and two, you only have two choices, multiply the two $3$'s or put them in different factors.

Combining them as $1$ and $3$, you have three different choices for the prime factors.

Making three non-trivial factors, you can multiply a $3$ with either $2$, $3$ or $7$, or you can multiply $2$ and $7$ for a total of $4$ ways to make the factors.

In total there are $1+3+2+3=10$ ways.

Comment: I have gone brute force and count 10.

Comment: Well, I missed $1\cdot 1\cdot 126$. if it's another way I'm missing from my argument, can you hint at what distribution of the prime factors I have I have the error is with?

Answer (score -1):

As you said, prime factors of 126 are 126=2*3*3*7

Then in order to make it as a product of 3 positive integer factors, you need to pick two out of four from these prime numbers and multiply them to get an integer, leaving the other two as prime. But since number 3 repeat twice, you need to divide by 2!

So there are $\frac{4C2}{2!} = 3$ ways

Comment: What about the factor 1? It is a positive integer factor as OP restricts factors.

Comment: $1*2*63$, $1*3*42$, $1*7*18$, $1*6*21$, $1*9*14$, that's 5 different ways (and your argument misses all of them) - and there's a couple more.

Comment: Even if you don't allow $1$ as a factor, you get $2\cdot3\cdot21$, $2\cdot7\cdot9$, $3\cdot6\cdot7$, and $3\cdot3\cdot14$.